# Bluetooth Not Available?

Tags: macbook-pro, snow-leopard, bluetooth, magic-trackpad

Mac OS X 10.6.4, MacBook Pro, Apple Magic Trackpad.

The trackpad is unresponsive. Right-clicking on the Bluetooth icon in the menu bar shows me gray text that says "Bluetooth not available".

I don't see a system preference item in which to fight with this, but I don't see anything relevant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this article](http://crschmidt.net/blog/archives/223/bluetooth-not-available-fixed/), resetting the System Management Controller might to the trick.

Here's how to [Reset the SMC](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3964) on Apple's support site.

Comment: I could not turn on Bluetooth and this helped. In short: 1. Shut down the computer. 2. Press and hold the start button for 10 seconds. 3. Wait for a few seconds and press the start button again to let the computer boot. Voilà!

Answer (score 2):

Under System Preferences there should be a bluetooth preference pane. Make sure it's set to 'on' and 'discoverable'.

Answer (score 1):

In terminal, also remove the com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad.plist and com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.mouse.plist files from ~/Library/Preferences.

```
cd ~/Library/Preferences
rm com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.mouse.plist
rm com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad.plist
```

Then restart.
That fixed it for me.

Comment: What does "also remove" mean here? What needs to be done addition to the removal of these files?

Comment: And why do you use `sudo` to remove files owned by the current user

Answer (score 0):

Resetting the NVRAM as described here solved the issue for me:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem since 2015 and I have tried just about everything suggested by this thread similar ones. The only solution I have come across that works 100% for me is by going to `System Preferences` -> `General` -> **unchecking** `Allow Handoff between this Mac and your iCloud devices`

It has been a month of observing this problem that occured daily and never had an issue afterwards. Hope this might help some of you out there.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it by

1. shutting down the machine
2. removing battery
3. keep power button pressed for 10 sec
4. start machine again

Comment: At which point did you insert the battery again, 2b? And how long did you remove it?

Comment: Better to follow the “how to reset SMC answer” since the steps vary per hardware.

Answer (score -1):

I have fixed by the same method as above.  shut down, remove battery, hold down power button for 10 seconds, replace battery and re-start

Comment: Better to follow the “how to reset SMC answer” since the steps vary per hardware.